# How do I store a JSON array to localstorage

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Fullname": "test name",
    "Username": "test",
    "Password": "$2a$10$f.upx2WTxlriul4QK/1GSuCxd6Dmw7.NgVeJ2VfuiC0uIZai5rsD6",
    "PasswordSalt": "$2a$10$uCpbT0wAGFx5NxCwlZOkK.",
    "Enabled": true,
    "Locked": false,
    "Deleted": false,
    "LogonAttempts": 0,
    "LastLogon": null,
    "LastModifiedBy": "Tester",
    "LastModifiedOn": "2020-09-14T16:08:35.853Z",
    "CreatedBy": "Tester",
    "CreatedOn": "2020-09-14T16:08:35.853Z",
    "UserRoles": [
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "Roles": "Admin",
            "RolePermissions": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "Permission": "Administrator"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "Permission": "Currency"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to save RolePermisions and then each Permission to local storage but I'm unsure on how to do this. Preferably I would like to do it inside ngOnInit()

TypeScript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,) { }
  access_token = null;

  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  }

}
```

I hope to be able to store the access_token as well as the RolePermision and each permission

Comment: stringify the JSON

Answer (score 1):

Do you specificatlly want to save RolePermissions and not UserRoles because a user will only have one role? Because if you want to store more than one role you should be storing UserRoles.
Anyways to store just RolePermissions and assuming that you always have one and that the object you have described above is stored in a variable called `userdata`, that would be:

```
localStorage.RolePermissions = JSON.stringify(userdata.UserRoles[0].RolePermissions);
```

to retrieve it you would do:

```
var permissions = JSON.parse(localStorage.RolePermissions);
```

Comment: Good spot, thanks yes I would like to store UserRoles what would be the best method of doing that?

Comment: I have a final question, I'm sorry to trouble you but how can i display this on the dashboard.component html page?

Comment: to store UserRoles is exactly the same process just use `userdata.UserRoles` instead of `userdata.UserRoles[0].RolePermissions` in the first statement. As far as how to display it on the dashboard page - your would be better of opening that as a separate question with some code from your template page.

Answer (score 0):

When storing to localStorage, you need to store data as string (so convert the permission data to string.) and when load the data from localStorage, you need to convert that string to array value.

Comment: const storeThisInLocalStorage = JSON.stringify(someJson);
then JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('yourdata'))

Comment: Yes, that will be okay.